# Store and retrieve arrayList from internal memory?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a home replacement app. I need to store the ArrayList with the apps the user picked to show on the launcher in the internal memory. I mean the array mustn't be deleted when the app is closed.

I'm very close to finishing the app and I don't think I'll work a lot more on Java, I'm not a programmer so I just want the easiest way to do it. How can I store and retrieve an ArrayList in the internal memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferenes` to store and retrieve the `arrayList`..

Check this link..

[Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Comment: Shared preferences is the easiest way to store persistently without db.

Answer (score 1):

You should store such data as Arraylists in the database and when you relaunch the app just fetch the data from database(SQLite) and display it to the user.

[Heres](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) a good tutorial on android SQLite.

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) link, for all the different data storage mechanisms in android. But for your requirement I would suggest using a db.

Comment: Using a relational Db for writing the content of an Array is a huge overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Java serialsation. It writes the content of an object to a (file-) outputstream. Thats a few lines of code. 
a bit better (faster, less bytes, readable by other non java systems) is to uses a custom serialisation, using DataOuputStream. That creates a binary file in the format you define.